# How can I create a global javascript object that can be accessed outside of my JS file?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following object in a JS file:

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function IOBreadcrumb() {
    this.breadcrumbs = [];
    this.add = function(title, url) {
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    };
  };
```

In another JS file I want to utilize this object:

```
//this occurs in some on click event
var breadcrumb = new IOBreadcrumb();
breadcrumb.add('some title',url);
console.log(breadcrumb.breadcrumbs);
```

I would like there to only be 1 instance of IOBreadcrumb, so that when I click on a button, it will always add a breadcrumb to the array.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry epascarello, new to JS and probably learned from a bad site. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var IOBreadcrumb = {
    breadcrumbs: [],
    add: function(title, url) {
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      IOBreadcrumb.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    }
  };
```

Then:

```
IOBreadcrumb.add('some title',url);
console.log(IOBreadcrumb.breadcrumbs);
```

Answer (score 5):

Make something like the following the first javascript that get's executed by your page.

```
(function(){
    var setup = function IOBreadcrumb() {
        this.breadcrumbs = [];
        this.add = function(title, url) {
            console.log('adding');
            var crumb = {
                title: title, 
                url:url
              };
            this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
        }
    };


  window.IOBreadcrumb = new setup();
})(window);
```

That does the initial setup.  Now from anywhere you can do

`IOBreadcrumb.add()`

I've tested this at http://jsfiddle.net/xmHh5/

What this does is assign `window.IOBreadcrumb` to the result of a function that is executed immediately.  Since there is no handle to this function, there is no way to re-execute it.  Since you are putting `IOBreadcrumb` on the window object, its effectively global.  I'm assuming this is running in a browser; it won't run on node.js or anything  because it depends on `window`.

Comment: Its global to all scripts on the page - accessed via window.IOBreadcrumb

Comment: or just IOBreadcrumb.add() from anywhere -- see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [Module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), which has the benefits of keeping breadcrumbs truly private. Not everyone is a fan of the module pattern though since it prevents monkey patching. This is especially problematic when you're using a library and you need to modify behavior but you don't want to  edit their source files to minimize troubles when upgrading. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/no-love-for-module-pattern

```
var IOBreadcrumb = (function() {
    var breadcrumbs = [];
    return {
       add: function(title, url) {
          breadcrumbs.push({
             title: title,
             url: url
          });
       },

       each: function (callback) {
          for (var i=0; i < breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
               callback(breadcrumbs[i].title, breadcrumbs[i].url);
          }
      }
    }
})();

IOBreadcrumb.add('title A', 'http://url.com/A');
IOBreadcrumb.add('title B', 'http://url.com/B');
IOBreadcrumb.add('title C', 'http://url.com/C');

IOBreadcrumb.each(function(title, url){
         console.log('Title', title, 'Url', url);
});
```